# IVY How to find specific dependency configuration is in use?

Tags: ant, ivy

I have my version.xml in a project where I defined all the IVY configurations and dependencies. I use ANT script to download and retrieve artefacts and everything is OK so far.

What I am looking for is that in anyway I can find if certain configuration is present in version.xml and some dependency is confgured to use it from an ANT script, like check as I want to do some extra stuff if it is configured other wise simply skip. For example my version.xml looks like as follows;

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://repository.temenosgroup.com/xsl/version-doc.xsl"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
    <info organisation="TEMENOS" branch="MAIN" module="StateEngine" />
    <!-- "war->compile(*)" this means the 'war' configuration depends on the
    'compile' configuration of the dependency and if the dependency is not
    found in 'compile' then use the 'default' (same as '*') config (usually that is all dependencies) -->
    <configurations defaultconfmapping="test->test(*);compile->compile(*);componentDep->componentDep(*)">
        <conf name="test" description="Test Time dependencies"/>
        <conf name="compile" description="Build Time dependencies"/>
       <conf name="componentDep" description="To resolve component level dependencies" />
    </configurations>
    <publications>
        <artifact name="#SERVICE_NAME#" type="" ext="zip" />
        <artifact name="#SERVICE_NAME#" type="" ext="zip" e:platform="#PLATFORM_WIN#" />
        <artifact name="#SERVICE_NAME#" type="" ext="zip" e:platform="#PLATFORM_UNIX#" />
    </publications>
    <dependencies>
        ....
        <!-- Define Component Level Dependencies Below -->
        <dependency org="TEMENOS" branch="MAIN" name="StateMachine" transitive="false" rev="latest-dev" conf="componentDep" >
            <artifact name="StateMachineService" ext="zip" e:platform="#PLATFORM_WIN#" type="" conf="componentDep" />
            <artifact name="StateMachineService" ext="zip" e:platform="#PLATFORM_UNIX#" type="" conf="componentDep" />
            <artifact name="StateMachineService" ext="zip" type="" conf="componentDep" /> 
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

So, is there any target available within ANT like 'ivy:...' which can return 'true' or 'false' some how tell me that there is a dependency which is trying to use configuration called 'componentDep'? so that I can do my extra stuff..otherwise skip. I do not want to parse the file myself within ANT as this is not a very good idea.

Note: I am using ANT 1.8.2 and IVY 2.2.0

Hope I am making sense. Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks,

--

Sjunejo

Comment: I have done it using <ivy:cachepath pathid="ivy.cache.path" conf="componentDep" /> ant task...if there are no dependencies defined then the path will be empty which can be used now to decide what to do next

Comment: Ahhh, now I understand what you're asking. Ivy files would normally specify project's dependencies. It would be very odd to declare a configuration and then not use it..... However in your case since I suspect you're generating the ivy files at runtime this becomes a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Ivy normally resolves using a file called **ivy.xml**.....

I suspect that your **version.xml** file is designed to be substituted? Perhaps your build is generating the ivy file at run-time?

## Reasons for suspicions

The names of the files published by ivy do not appear valid.... I doubt you're creatung 3 files called **#SERVICE_NAME#.zip**

```
<publications>
    <artifact name="#SERVICE_NAME#" type="" ext="zip" />
    <artifact name="#SERVICE_NAME#" type="" ext="zip" e:platform="#PLATFORM_WIN#" />
    <artifact name="#SERVICE_NAME#" type="" ext="zip" e:platform="#PLATFORM_UNIX#" />
</publications>
```

Somewhere else in your build I think there's a filtered copy going on.....

## Possible answer to your original question

I think you're looking for an [ivy resolution report](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/report.html)? This creates a HTML report of the files associated with each of your project's configurations. Used as follows:

```
<target name="init">
    <ivy:resolve/>

    <ivy:report todir='${ivy.reports.dir}' graph='false' xml='false'/>

     ..
</target>
```